# MYSQL INSERT not working

Tags: php, mysql, insert

I don't understand why my MY_SQL insert isn't working.

```
<?php
$sub = $_POST['submit'];


if($sub)
{

$title = $_COOKIE['newstitle'];
$body = $_COOKIE['newsbody'];
$sneak = $_COOKIE['newssneak'];
$date = date("Y-d-m");
$postedby = $_COOKIE['userlogin'];

$connect = mysql_connect("localhost","admin","00904684") or die("Couldn't Connect!");
mysql_select_db("dr") or die("Couldn't find DB.");

$insert = mysql_query
("
INSERT INTO news(`id`,`title`,`summary`,`body`,`date`,`postedby`)
VALUES ('NULL','".$title."','".$sneak."','".$body."','".$date."','".$postedby."')
");
mysql_close($connect);



header('Location: ../index.php');


}
else echo (mysql_error());

?>
```

My code used to work until i added a new feild "Summary" into it, ever since it hasn't worked, i know the variables are passing correctly though.

Here is my database layout:

> id | title | summary | body | date | postedby

Comment: Add a `if (!$insert) echo mysql_error();` to see what error(s) mySQL is throwing

Comment: What error do you have? What if I edit my `newstitle` cookie to have a value of `" OR 1=1;`? `mysql_real_escape_string()` is your friend in this example, or PDO is an even better friend :)

Comment: 1. *please* read about mysql_real_escape_string -- 2. try echoing mysql_error() right after the query to see the error you are getting and post it here. thanks

Answer (score 3):

Are you allowed to have the ID be NULL you could try this instead

```
INSERT INTO news(`title`,`summary`,`body`,`date`,`postedby`)
VALUES ('".$title."','".$sneak."','".$body."','".$date."','".$postedby."')
```

by removing the Id field from the insert it will be what ever the default is be it null or auto inc.

Answer (score 2):

You are not escaping your input, which leaves you wide open to SQL injection - which is likely your problem. I'd bet the "summary" has a single quote in the content, which is breaking your query. You should be doing:

```
$title = mysql_real_escape_string($_COOKIE['newstitle']);
$body = mysql_real_escape_string($_COOKIE['newsbody']);
$sneak = mysql_real_escape_string($_COOKIE['newssneak']);
$date = date("Y-d-m");
$postedby = mysql_real_escape_string($_COOKIE['userlogin']);
```

Comment: That's a good shout. I can't see any syntax problems so this is a good bet. +1

Answer (score 0):

If you're actually meaning to insert the string 'NULL' into the ID field, you should be fine. I'm suspecting that you mean to install NULL (notice no quotes), meaning 'no value'. If that's the case, remove the quotes, or as @nhutto said remove the column altogether.

Answer (score 0):

Heres my try.

```
<?php

if($sub)
{
    $title       = mysql_real_escape_string($_COOKIE['newstitle']);
    $body        = mysql_real_escape_string( $_COOKIE['newsbody']);
    $postedby    = mysql_real_escape_string($_COOKIE['userlogin']);
    $sneak       = mysql_real_escape_string($_COOKIE['newssneak']);
    $date        = date('Y-d-m');

    $connect = mysql_connect('Localhost', 'admin', '00904684') or die('Could not connect to database.');
               mysql_select_db('dr') or die('Could not find database.');

    $insert  = mysql_query('INSERT_INTO news(`title`, `summary`, `body`, `date`, `postedby`) 
                                        VALUES(\''. $title . '\', \''. $sneak . '\', \''. $body . '\', \''. $date . '\', \''. $postedby . '\')');
               mysql_close();

    header('Location: ../index.php');
}
else {
    echo mysql_error();
}
```